# Submit form with ajax, asynchronously with a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I realize SO is loaded with material on this subject, I've gone through it, but just can't seem to get this to work.

My function takes a JSON response, parses it and returns a false on success and true on error (This is backwards on purpose).

console.log shows I'm getting the correct response, but my function won't return (`submitme` remains false although it is changed to `true` inside the callback). Thus, the function always returns false.

<s>I'm guessing my callback operation is faulty but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.</s>
I might be off here, but I think the callback is OK, it is just being executed after the script is executed (hence asynchronous).
But my question remains, how in this case can I have the form submit true if the boolean value is only being changed via ajax?

Here's my snippet:

```js
$(".form").submit(function(){
    error = $("#error");
    var submitme = false;

    function ajaxCall(url, type, data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            try {
            obj = JSON.parse(response);
            text = obj.Error;
            error.html('');
            error.append(text);
            //if the json was parsed, return false
            submitform = false;
            }
            catch (error) {
                //if an error was thrown, return true
                submitform = true;
                }
            callback(submitform);
        },
    });

    }

    function ajaxCallSuccess(submitform) {
        console.log(submitform); //This shows correct output!
        if (submitform == 'true'){ //Here I want to manipulate the global submitme variable so I can submit the form on "true"
            submitme = true; //<-- this (I think) changes the global variable asynchronousy (so after the function is read), hence the outer function always returns false
        }

    };

    ajaxCall(url, type, data, ajaxCallSuccess);


    if (submitme == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**
I edited the post to perhaps clarify the question a little bit

Comment: what's the output here in your console for "submitform":
console.log(submitform);

Comment: @Sunny Notice the try block inside the ajax call, submitform returns `false` on successful parse of `response` (obj = JSON.parse(response)) and `true` on error. console.log outputs the correct boolean values depending on whether the response is a JSON object or not, I just can't seem to get those values out of the `ajaxCall` function. This is what determines whether the form submits or not.

Comment: dear friend, error is global variable?

Comment: @FUserThrowError I'm not getting an error, just not the output I need. Have a look at `function ajaxCallSuccess`, I'm attempting to change the `submitme` variable from there with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to always return false and then manually submit the form in case the AJAX call succeeds:

```
$('.form').submit(function() {
    function ajaxCall(url, type, data, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                callback(true);
            },
            error: function() {
                callback(false);
            }
        });
    }

    var form = $(this);

    function ajaxCallSuccess(submitform) {
        if (submitform) {
            // submit the form here:
            form[0].submit();
        }
    };

    ajaxCall(url, type, data, ajaxCallSuccess);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Submitting the form from inside the callback sends me off on an infinite loop, because it basically keeps sending requests to this very function which returns false

Comment: That's correct. I made a mistake in my answer. You should invoke the submit function on the native DOM element using `form[0].submit();` instead of invoking it on the jQuery element which would trigger the .submit event handler using `form.submit();`. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: forms (plural) works for me as opposed to form (singular). I don't know if you want to change that in your answer. Either way, it works so thank you.

Answer (score -2):

> I realize SO is loaded with material on this subject, I've gone through it, but just can't seem to get this to work.

Why? Have you not *understood* what was explained there …?

> But my question remains, how in this case can I have the form submit true if the boolean value is only being changed via ajax?

You *can not* return a value out of an asynchronous handler, and expect that value to be available in the code that follows it, *because* of the asynchronous execution. The following code will not “wait” for the asynchronous action to be finished, that’s the whole *point* of asynchronism.

So cancel the submitting of the form right away – and then submit the form from within your callback function if applicable.

Comment: Obviously he doesn't understand, that's why he's asking the question.